# Is "Stop making terrible edits" a valid suggested edit rejection reason?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

Recently after rejecting [a suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11174071) I checked how other reviewers reviewed this edit suggestion and I noticed that [one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1315962/andrewsi) gave custom rejection message:

> Stop making terrible edits

I don't think that's helpful to the person who suggested this edit, because it doesn't tell anything besides that this edit is bad. What should be done with this? Should the reviewer be somehow notified that this rejection reason is wrong?

Comment: The linked Q&A suggests flagging the post being edited for moderator attention.

Comment: The reviewer is spot on though, those suggested edits _are_ terrible.

Comment: @tristan I'm not saying that he is wrong, but that he gave a rejection reason that will not help the author of the suggested edit.

Comment: @Gothdo the reviewer in question will know what's up.  I'd bet you $100 that the terrible suggested edits from that user will stop shortly after he hits 2000 rep and he stops getting _dem sweet internet pointz_.

Comment: The Road to Rep: find a common typo. In this case, 'andriod'. Hey, I think I got a great new name for my next program!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, taking a look at [that user's suggested edits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/800505/warren-sergent-spakatak-com?tab=activity&sort=suggestions), I can easily understand the rejecting user's frustration with someone who consistently submits lots of edit-suggestions following that same pattern.

Yes, the edit-rejection-reason is not quite the right way to voice that problem.
A moderator-attention-flag with details and lots of examples is probably more productive.
Or asking in a receptive chat-room for help pushing against the flood.
Preferably, after having failed to engage the user on one of his accepted edits to try to get him to improve his behavior.